# activiti send transaction process to specific candidate group dynamically

Tags: javascript, spring, workflow, activiti, bpmn

Here is the workflow that I would like to work-on:

> In the Fill-up form section, the user needs to select which area to be
>   processed (area1, area2, area3). There will be 3 reviewers and each one
>   is assigned to the specific areas (reviewer1 to area1, reviewer2 to
>   area2, reviewer3 to area3), same with the managers.

How can I redirect the transaction process based on the selected area made by the user to its designated reviewers? Can this be achieved via coding thru listeners?

Another question is that, how can I retrieve/use execution variable inside form javascript section? I tried using `execution.getVariable` function but failed to publish the process flow.

I'm using activiti 5.19

Workflow Sample:
[image]